# Stream of strings matching a simple regexp in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

This is a follow-up to my previous question. Suppose I would like to make a `Stream` of all strings matching `^a+b+$` (one or more "a" and then one or more "b").

I am coding it as follows:

```
def interleave(s1:Stream[String], s2:Stream[String]): Stream[String] =
  if (s1.isEmpty) s2 else Stream.cons(s1.head, interleave(s2, s1.tail))

def generate(s1:Stream[String], s2:Stream[String]): Stream[String] =
  if (s1.isEmpty) s1 else interleave(s2.map(s1.head + _), generate(s1.tail, s2))

def as:Stream[String] = Stream.cons("a", as.map(_ + "a"))

def bs:Stream[String] = Stream.cons("b", bs.map(_ + "b"))

def solve = generate(as, bs)
```

Unfortunately `solve` fails with `out of memory`. However it works fine for finite streams: for instance `solve(as take 10, bs take 10)`

How would you fix the code above? Would you prefer another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Just a side remark: you say you want a series of a then b, but don't anchor your regex with `$`? Why is that?

Comment: @fge you are right. I am fixing the regexp.

Comment: the `s2` param to `generate` should be `Stream[String]` i assume, not `Stream[Stream]`. also there is a missing closing brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in order to be able to call `interleave`, `generate` must be computed:

```
def generate(s1:Stream[String], s2:Stream[String]): Stream[String] =
  if (s1.isEmpty) ... else interleave(..., generate(s1.tail, s2))
```

So generate will recursive call itself until `s1.isEmpty`, at which point it will finally call all the hanging `interleave`'s. Since `s1` is infinite, it will never be empty.

If you turn the second parameter of `interleave` into a by-name parameter, then the recursion can be deferred:

```
def interleave(s1:Stream[String], s2: => Stream[String]): Stream[String] =
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this one:

```
scala> val asbs = for(n <- Stream.from(2);k <- 1 until n) yield "a"*k + "b"*(n-k)
asbs: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] = Stream(ab, ?)

scala> asbs.take(10).toList
res0: List[String] = List(ab, abb, aab, abbb, aabb, aaab, abbbb, aabbb, aaabb, aaaab)

scala>
```